# Concurrency in Kotlin

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, kotlin

I have a class that has a nullable variable that is written by multiple thread, something like

```
class A {
    var s: String? = null //var accessed by multiple threads

    fun doStuff() {
        if (s != null) {
            //not safe
        }
    }
}
```

To counter this, I usually make an immutable copy like so

```
class A {
    var s: String? = null //var accessed by multiple threads

    fun doStuff() {
        val sCopy = s
        if (sCopy != null) {
            //safe now
        }
    }
}
```

I read about concurrency tools like volatile, synchronized etc but I'm not good at multithreading yet to know how should I handle it and I'm pretty sure there is better ways to achieve this than creating an immutable value, how would you do it?

Comment: To clarify, is that inner block performing writes to `s` in both cases?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No it doesn't

Comment: Oh, so where are the writes happening?  FWIW, using `synchronized` is probably the brute-force solution here.

Comment: it is written by an other thread in an other class, should I put @synchronized on the "doStuff()" method?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend containing a shared mutable variable within a single class. Having some external code write to the variable is asking for trouble. If it's completely encapsulated in one class, you can guarantee thread-safety for users of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reuse Java tooling in these cases.

For most simple cases, you would create an object (can be of any type) that will be used as the *lock* and use that lock for every single access to your state. There's the `synchronized` function which even let's you return a value directy:

```
val anyLock = Any()
fun syncWithArbitraryObjTest(): Int = synchronized(anyLock) { 123 }
```

Note that `synchronized` is a function in Kotlin which returns a value. This makes it more powerful than Java's synchronized keyword. Technically it doesn’t make a difference on which object you lock, as long as you use the same object for all relevant code blocks that need be `synchronized` with each other.

If you choose to use a specific `Lock` object, e.g. an instance of `ReentrantLock`, you may use `withLock` instead:

```
val lock = ReentrantLock()
fun syncWithLockTest(): Int = lock.withLock { 123 }
```

---

Last but not least, your code `val sCopy = s` is no copy of `s`, it's simply a second variable pointing to *the same* object; this code isn't any safer.

Comment: I'm a little confused how this `synchronized` reduces boilerplate when compared to Java's. It's nice being able to express it as a library function instead of a language feature, sure, but boilerplate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to lock both the writes and the reads to your variable, like this:

```
class A {
    var s: String? = null //var accessed by multiple threads
     set(s) {
         synchronized(this) {
             field = s
         }
    }

    fun doStuff() {
        synchronized(this) {
            //safe now    
        }
    }
}
```

You need the synchronized in the setter beacuse otherwise the value might be overwritten while a thread is in doStuff.

Though in general it's better to avoid situations where multiple threads can write the same variable.